# Book recommendation to know and understand the brain and the phenomena and processes related to it

Tags: neuroscience, brain, biophysics, book-recommendation

I need a book recommendation or, more properly, any source recommendation to know and understand more about the phenomena related to the brain, as far as we know how the brain works. I'm interested in the very structure the brain has and how it leads to what we experience. Due to the way biological processes happen, how the things we define for ourselves are related to each other. It would be cool if it adds more to the biophysics of those processes and the possible picture of their evolution, as well as the physical characteristics of those biological structures.

Comment: I have been away from stackexchange for long if the question is not according to the site's guidelines please edit it or if you can make the question better please do it (I know I wasn't that good at it). I didn't find any other question or answer helping so I asked it, if there's any question or answer already that can help please add it into comments.

Comment: Your question would be a better fit on [CognitiveSciences.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com). In fact your question is possibly a duplicate of [this post](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/287/modern-replacement-for-panksepps-affective-neuroscience-book).

Comment: I'd agree with @Remi.b to check CogSci - the recommendations in the linked question will probably get most of what you want, but your question touches on a lot of areas that probably won't all be found in detail in the same book; you will probably find more on biophysics in a more basic neuroscience textbook like [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23403/book-recommended-for-neurobiology?rq=1); I'd expect more coverage of evolution of behavior in an Animal Behavior textbook.

Comment: My other advice is that I'd recommend staying away from "evolutionary psychology" because that field is tainted with a lot of pseudoscience and disguised speculation, and it will be difficult to evaluate the claims critically without a lot of background knowledge.

Comment: @Remi.b the books suggested into the answers to that question possibly aren't answering the questions i do have, neither there's much of discussion about the books in the answer. I checked on CogSci.SE few simillar questions were there but the recommended books weren't really getting around what i want as I have mentioned in the question, and few were bit perspective based.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yeah what I want I might not get in the single book , It's not necessary for it to be a single book but the ones which are really good getting around the questions. Ok I will remember your advice. And the question you mentioned helped. I found recommendation of those same books before coming to SE,they seem to be bit expensive purchase but yeah they seem going with the subject. It will be helpful if somebody can recommend some similar books not that long and expensive but as cool as them. If you think I will get better answers to the question on CogSci can my question be migrated?

Comment: Probably the best options for general knowledge are going to be textbooks, which unfortunately are going to be expensive. However, there are also lots of used textbooks, so you might be able to find a used, older edition of the books that people recommend that is much more affordable. There are some more affordable books in the pop-science category, but those can be problematic; Steven Pinker for example is an entertaining writer, but his books are meant to be persuasive: he won't give you an unbiased perspective of the literature (and one of the reasons I warned about evolutionary psychology)